# Как написать таймер на C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно узнать сколько прошло время между нажатий кнопки GetMouseButtonDown(0) и GetMouseButtonUp(0)
Таймер должен включаться по нажатию GetMouseButtonDown(0) и выключаться GetMouseButtonUp(0)
И в переменную записываться время.

Пример:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
 {
        //Старт таймер
 }
if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
{
        //Стоп таймер
        
 }

 float x = //Время от Старт до Стоп
```

Comment: StopWatch? Или просто запомнить `DateTime.Now`, если не нужна огромная точность.

Comment: Этот участник никак не реагирует, ни на ответы, не на комментарии. Смысла отвечать ему примерно никакого.

Comment: Я новичок, не могу разобраться в ответах, в лямбда выражениях

Comment: Так приведите пример кода, который у вас не работает, задайте более конкретный вопрос. Сам вопрос можно редактировать.

Comment: _не могу разобраться в ответах, в лямбда выражениях_ => [ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions).

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time.html

Answer (score -1):

```
DateTime press;
DateTime up;
TimeSpan delta => up - press;
void MousePress() => press = DateTime.Now;
void MouseUp()
{
    up = DateTime.Now;
    WriteLine($"Разница во времени: {delta}");
}

//MousePress();
//MouseUp();
//Разница во времени: 00:00:05.1762961
```

Comment: поскольку delta имеет смысл только после отпускания мыши, возможно, имеет смысл не делать из этого свойство, а вычислить прямо в `MouseUp`

Answer (score -2):

```
private readonly Stopwatch _sw=new Stopwatch();
void MouseDown () {_sw.Restart();}
void MouseUp()
        {
            _sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(_sw.Elapsed.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]